# Is it possible use AuthorizeAttribute with a external api call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, restsharp

i'm working with asp mvc 5, and i have to schedule some tasks, so i want to create a simple methods to be called from a simple console program C# and schedule them with Windows Task Scheduler.

The think is, i'm using Identity with `Authorize` attribute to manage the user permissions.

For example, i have the next method:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public async Task<JsonResult> CriticalTask(string someParam)
{
 //procesing data
 return null;
}
```

The think, is:

I dont know how can i do the login to pass the validation from the `Authorize(Roles="Admin")`

I try creating a simple method to login before it, but that doesn't work

I'm trying some like this

```
        const string URL = "http://localhost:53665/";
        RestClient mClient = new RestClient(URL);
        const string parameterUserName = "userName";
        const string parameterPassword = "password";
        const string ruta = "Usuarios/ApiLogin";

        var request = new RestRequest(ruta);

        request.AddParameter(parameterUserName, "userName");
        request.AddParameter(parameterPassword, "password");

        //Method to login
        var result2 = mClient.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine($"Login\n{result2.Content}");

        //Method that needs Admin permissions
        request = new RestRequest("Usuarios/Test");
        var result3 = mClient.Execute(request);

        Console.WriteLine($"Test\n{result3.Content}");
```

is that possible only with Authorize attribute? or i need to implement some token method to authorize this calls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use BasicAuth - you pass Credentials in headers for each request, and each request is validated separately - search for MVC Basic auth fr sample setup. I's the easiest form - but also very insecure as you pass your credentials in each call in almost plain text (it is only base64 of your credentials)

I'd suggest you to use Identity Server 4 to authorize your client using bearer token.

this way before first call you request token from server and then pass it to following requests and use this to authorize your api calls.

see following tutorial about setup.
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

in following url you can see example of in memory users, but also token requests.it's easy but obsolete
https://neelbhatt.com/2018/03/04/step-by-step-setup-for-the-auth-server-and-the-client-identityserver4-with-net-core-part-ii/

you can also use some sort of following code to obtain token in less obsolete way:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
    var discovery = await _httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(_configuration["ApiBaseAddress"]);

    if (discovery.IsError)
    {
          return false;
    }

    request.Address = discovery.TokenEndpoint;
    request.ClientId = _configuration["AuthClientName"];
    request.ClientSecret = _configuration["AuthClientSecret"];

    var request = new PasswordTokenRequest
           {
                UserName = "yourUserName",
                Password = "yourPassword"
            };
    var token = await _httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(request);
}
```

in `token.AccessToken` you have your access token - the one needed to be sent to call api. you also have your refresh token in `token.RefreshToken` - it will be useful later

then to send call simply add bearer token to your HttpRequestMessage and it's done

```
var _httpClient =  new HttpClient();
//Configure your http client here
var req= new HttpRequestMessage("http request method", "request uri");
req.SetBearerToken("your access token goes here);
var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(req);
```

keep in mind that after you receive permission denied it's better to refresh token than obtain another one (you don't need to send your credentials). You use your refresh token i mentioned earlier.

The code for refreshing token is very similar to obtaining token by login/password. Just instead of `PasswordTokenRequest` class use following class:

```
var request = new RefreshTokenRequest
{
    RefreshToken = _refreshToken
};
```

and instead `httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(request)` use `httpClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(request)`. rest of code may remain similar.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to save the received token after login and then add the token to request header which needs to be authorized:

```
     var result = mClient.Execute(request);
     string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      //This token will be used for authorization
     var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(resultContent);

     var request = new RestRequest("Usuarios/Test");  //add token to header of request
     mClient.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("bearer {0}", token.Access_Token));
     var result3 = mClient.Execute(request);
```

Token model:

```
   public class TokenModel
   {
      ...
      public string Access_Token { get; set; }
      ...
   }
```

Comment: when using `HttpClient` instead of `RestRequest` you can use already provided method tor adding header: `SetBearerToken`. But code above looks ok - i just don;t like RestRequest class as i found some strange behavior for some of http response codes - i wanted to find what it was, but i saw that we replaced all usages of RestRequest in our solution and i forgot what it was :/

Answer (score 0):

I end up creating a custom attribute, based on the [reply](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/282321/77052) posted by [crrlos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/55132/crrlos) in [StackOverflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com).

I will translate it as best I can so that it can serve others

> What you can do is create a custom authorization attribute, for that
>   you create a class that inherits `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the
>   `AuthorizeCore` method. The modification consists in passing to the
>   route an additional parameter to indicate that it is calling from the
>   task scheduler, if the parameter is not found then it will perform the
>   normal validation, if the parameter is found (it must have a value or
>   if it will not be null ) Then take the credentials of the url and
>   perform the validation, if they are correct return a true allowing
>   access to the method.
>
> ```
> public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
> {
>     protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>     {
>       //get special parameter indicating that the request was made from the task scheduler
>       var parametro = httpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("parametro_especial");
>
>       if(parametro != null)
>       {
>         // get access credentials and validate them
>         // if they are valid, return true
>       }
>       //if they are not valid, or aren't present
>       //try with deffault validate.
>       return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> How to use it?
>
> ```
> [CustomAuthorization (Roles = "Admin")]
>    public JsonResult CargarTodosLosArticulos()
>    {
>        return null;
>    }
> ```